# Nhibernate syntax problem?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Well i am rather new to nhibrenate syntax and need desperately your help.

I have a table called **Cookie** with the following attributes:

```
Id(int) , Datetime(datetime), UniqueId (string) , IsTransaction(bool)
```

All i want is to produce a list of the above table like this

```
Id     Datetime     UniqueId    IsTransaction
       25/8/2011    789              1
       23/8/2011    789              0
       22/8/2011    789              0
       20/8/2011    789              0
       20/8/2011    789              0
       20/8/2011    789              1
       19/8/2011    789              0
       18/8/2011    789              0
       25/8/2011    111              1
       24/8/2011    111              0
       23/8/2011    111              0
       20/8/2011    111              0
       17/8/2011    111              0
       15/8/2011    111              1
       13/8/2011    111              0
       12/8/2011    111              0
       11/8/2011    111              0
       10/8/2011    111              0
```

To be honest i find it difficult do write that query even in plain SQL :(

Any ideas??

Thanks!

Comment: Surely it's just an order by descending on Datetime, UniqueId and IsTransaction? What's the problem? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why do you want to write it in plain sql if you're using Nhibernate ?

Comment: @Frederik Sorry i find it difficult even in plain SQL:)

Comment: Please start by reading the reference http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session.CreateQuery("from Cookie").List();
```

//optionally you can add the  where condition like this

```
session.CreateQuery("from Cookie where IsTransaction=1").List();
```

Both the above code is in HQL or you can use SQL as follows:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("select * from Cookie");
```

//optionally you can add the  where condition like this

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("select * from Cookie where IsTransaction=1").List();
```

instead of the * you could give your column names too if you want to select only a few columns.. I dont know why your Id field is empty..

Comment: This would do it for me. Thanks!